# What does this mean? from the Haskell wiki

Tags: haskell

```
data Exp  
  = Let String Exp Exp
  | Exp1 Exp1
  deriving Show
```

What does the Let keyword from the [documentation page](http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-using.html) example mean? (I am aware of the normal meaning of let)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a keyword. It's simply a name given to the first constructor of the `Exp` type. The first `Exp1` on the second line is the name of the second constructor.

Comment: So using this data type I would actually write "Let "a_string" Exp Exp?

Comment: Yes, to create a value of type `Exp` you'd either write `Let "string" someExp someOtherExp` or `Exp1 someExp1`. There's nothing special about the name `Let` here - it acts just like any other constructor.

Comment: As a full Haskell expression: `let x = Let "var" someExp otherExp in show x`.  Or even as a recursive data structure: `let x = Let "var" x x in show x`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `Let` is a data constructor and shouldn't be confused with `let` keyword.
In the example the grammar accepts the `let` expressions like the one used by Haskell.
I.e. the string `let foo = 5 in foo + foo` will later be represented as:
`Let "foo" (Term (Factor (Int 5))) (Plus (Term (Factor (Var "foo"))) (Factor (Var "foo")))`

As you can see the first argument to the constructor is substition and the second argument is the expression the substition applies to.

Comment: `Let` is a data constructor, not a type constructor.